# Terraform - Use data source output in variable default

Tags: terraform

I am creating a module to spin up a basic web server.

I am trying to get it so that if the user does not specify an AMI then the ubuntu image for that region is used.

I have a `data` block to get the AMI ID of the ubuntu 16.04 image for that region but I cannot set this as the default for a variable as interpolation does not work.

My module is as follows:-

main.tf

```
resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  ami = "${var.aws_ami}"
  instance_type = "${var.instance_type}"
  security_groups = ["${aws_security_groups.web.id}"]

  tags {
      Name = "WEB_SERVER"
  }
}

resource "aws_security_groups" "web" {
  name = "WEB_SERVER-HTTP-HTTPS-SG"

  ingress {
      from_port = "${var.http_port}"
      to_port = "${var.http_port}"
      protocol = "tcp"
      cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"] 
  }

  ingress {
      from_port = "${var.https_port}"
      to_port = "${var.https_port}"
      protocol = "tcp"
      cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
      from_port = 0
      to_port = 0
      protocol = "-1"
      cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}
```

variables.tf

```
variable "instance_type" {
  description = "The instance size to deploy. Defaults to t2.micro"
  default = "t2.micro"
}

variable "http_port" {
  description = "The port to use for HTTP traffic. Defaults to 80"
  default = "80"
}

variable "https_port" {
  description = "The port to use for HTTPS traffic. Defaults to 443"
  default = "443"
}



data "aws_ami" "ubuntu" {
    filter {
        name = "state"
        values = ["available"]
    }

    filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-xenial-16.04-amd64-server-*"]
  }

    filter {
        name   = "virtualization-type"
        values = ["hvm"]
    }

    owners = ["099720109477"]

}

locals {
  default_ami = "${data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id}"
}

variable aws_ami {
    description = "The AMI used to launch the instance. Defaults to Ubuntu 16.04"
    default = "${local.default_ami}"
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using a ternary operator interpolation:

```
variable "user_specified_ami" {
  default = "ami-12345678"
}

resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  ami = "${var.user_specified_ami == "" ? data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id : var.user_specified_ami}"
  # ... other params omitted ....
}
```

Set `user_specified_ami`'s default to something to use that AMI. Set it to blank to use the AMI ID Terraform gets from the AWS provider.

i.e. if `user_specified_ami` is anything other blank (""), then it will be chosen for the AMI, else the AMI Terraform gets the one from AWS.

BTW, maybe you want to use the `most_recent = true` param in the `data "aws_ami"` resource?

Comment: Why are you setting a default for `user_specified_ami` other than `""`? It seems like that would be a cleaner API to the module where it defaults to the data source AMI normally unless `user_specified_ami` is set.

Comment: Yep, true. I wasn't paying attention to the module aspect of things as I didn't want to overcomplicate the essence of the solution.

Answer (score 6):

A similar solution to the other answers, but using the [coalesce function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/coalesce.html):

```
variable "user_specified_ami" {
  default = ""
}

resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  ami = coalesce(var.user_specified_ami, data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

KJH's answer works great, but it felt a bit messy to me to have that logic inline, so I made an abstraction using [null_data_source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/null/data_source.html). Here's what that would look like:

```
variable "ami" {
  default = ""
}

data "null_data_source" "data_variables" {
  inputs = {
    ami = "${var.ami == "" ? data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id : var.ami}"
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  ami = "${data.null_data_source.data_variables.outputs["ami"]}"
  # ... other params omitted ....
}
```